# Anybody knows how to stop caching in opencart 2 completely?

Tags: caching, opencart2.3

Although I delete the whole content of 'catalog/product/product' and replace it with the code below, but still browsers show the same page.

The problem is I'm not able to force the page to show changes I do in CODE page.

I've tried most of the solutions offered in many many forums.

UPDATE: I've deleted cached files of browser, opencart project, even I've tried a different browser on a different device!

```
<?php
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->cache->delete('product');
        print_r('<hr><hr><hr>all deleted!');
    }
}
```

Comment: remove browser cache...

Comment: @PritamKumbhar: I've deleted cached files of browser, opencart project, even I've tried a different browser on a different device!

Comment: Remove ocmod and vqmod caches too.

Comment: @MojtabaSabeti, I fixed the problem and posted the answer, ba tashakkor!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot at last I found that Opencart saves a copy of some files as **cache** not only in **cache** folder (/system/storage/cache) but in folder: **system/storage/modification/** too.

The exact page that caused this caching problem was *(/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/product/product.php)*.

The problem could be fixed in two ways:

1. Deleting **product.php** in above mentioned folder.
2. Refresh Modification from Opencart control panel.

A similar post:
[How does the Opencart system/modifications folder function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100072/how-does-the-opencart-system-modifications-folder-function)

Comment: You didn't need step 1. step 2 delete all files in modification folder. ba tashakkor ☺